# Rails application with Apache on Windows Server

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, ruby-on-rails, windows-server-2019, ruby-rack

I need to migrate an existing Rails application (Redmine) on a Windows Server 2019 machine. It's been requested to use Apache as web server. The application runs correctly on localhost through webrick, but i'm encountering difficulties on serving it.

I tried using [this guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache), but I can't download mongrel_service-0.3.4-i386-mswin32.gem as the link is dead and can't find it anywhere else.

Trying to run 'gem install mongrel_service' returned this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing mongrel_service:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastthread-1.0.7/ext/fastthread

C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20190607-7092-128t9mk.rb extconf.rb
extconf.rb:13:in `block in <main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
        from extconf.rb:12:in open'
        from extconf.rb:12:in <main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I tried to run it following [this](https://www.benkirane.ch/deployment-rails-4-app-windows/) guide (on port 80 for the moment, not using the Bitnami stack but regular Apache), but not using anything else I can see the /public directory listing and not the application working.

Phusion Passenger doesn't exist on Windows and [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack) does not appear to support Apache out of the box, if I got it right.

How could I make it run correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Apache ver: 2.4.35
Ruby ver: 2.5.3p105
Rails ver: 4.2.11
Bundler ver: 1.17.3

my vhosts file:

```
    # Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/redmine"

    <Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/redmine/public" >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

    # <Proxy *>
    #     Order allow,deny
    #     Allow from all
    # </Proxy>
    # <Proxy balancer://thin_cluster>
    #     BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
    #     BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
    # </Proxy>

    # ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:80/
    #ProxyPassReverse / balancer://thin_cluster/
    #ProxyReserveHost on

    # RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect all non-static requests to Rails server,
    # but serve static assets via Apache
    # RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://thin_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

    # # Support for far-futures expires header
    # <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
    #     Header unset ETag
    #     FileETag None
    #     # RFC says only cache for 1 year
    #     ExpiresActive On
    #     ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    # </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Redmine is not well supported in Windows. Is there some reason this must run in Windows?

Comment: Yes Michael, it's been required by the customer to use a Windows server